# resolving the error due to xen building\installation

Tags: makefile, build, xen, arch

can't resolve the error when I am trying to build xen package using manjaro linux and 5.11.6-1 kernel.
Really appreciate fro thoughts. Thanks.

```
  ...

  GEN     target/sparc/trace.c
  GEN     util/trace.c
  GEN     config-all-devices.mak
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/username/xen/src/xen-4.14.1/tools/qemu-xen/slirp'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/username/xen/src/xen-4.14.1/tools/qemu-xen/slirp'
  BUILD   pc-bios/optionrom/multiboot.img
  BUILD   pc-bios/optionrom/linuxboot.img
  BUILD   pc-bios/optionrom/linuxboot_dma.img
  BUILD   pc-bios/optionrom/kvmvapic.img
ld: Error: unable to disambiguate: -no-pie (did you mean --no-pie ?)
ldmake[1]: *** [Makefile:53: multiboot.img] Error 1
: Error: unable to disambiguate: -no-pie (did you mean --no-piemake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 ?)
make[1]: *** [Makefile:53: linuxboot.img] Error 1
ld: Error: unable to disambiguate: -no-pie (did you mean --no-pie ?)
ld: Error: unable to disambiguate: -no-pie (did you mean --no-pie ?)
make[1]: *** [Makefile:53: kvmvapic.img] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:53: linuxboot_dma.img] Error 1
  BUILD   pc-bios/optionrom/pvh.img
ld: Error: unable to disambiguate: -no-pie (did you mean --no-pie ?)
make[1]: *** [Makefile:50: pvh.img] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:581: pc-bios/optionrom/all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/username/xen/src/xen-4.14.1/tools/qemu-xen-build'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:218: subdir-all-qemu-xen-dir] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/username/xen/src/xen-4.14.1/tools'
make[2]: *** [/home/username/xen/src/xen-4.14.1/tools/../tools/Rules.mk:235: subdirs-install] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/username/xen/src/xen-4.14.1/tools'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:72: install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/username/xen/src/xen-4.14.1/tools'
make: *** [Makefile:134: install-tools] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward to me: you have a linker option `-no-pie` somewhere in your makefiles, but the linker wants the option `--no-pie` (note the extra initial dash).

Comment: Thanks for the routing me on the right way did not noticed that dash. I have searched about this problem for a while and seems like it comes from ld/lexsup.c of binutils package. http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/Linker-diagnostics-for-the-incorrect-options-td646580.html